# Forge Viewer: 2D view rooms

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do I get a list of all rooms on a 2D view and color code the rooms? I can get the list of views using the api ofcourse but how to I color code them in the viewer?

Comment: If you have the root node and thus its dbId you could use `setThemingColor` to color them accordingly. [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive)

Comment: I would think the challenge to InsaneKarma is how to get room information, e,g. which range of curves build a room, or if there is additional geometries to represent a room like 3D master view does.  I do not find such data right now. will dig into and get back

Comment: Sorry for letting you wait.  I am told sheets and 2d views are exported through DWFx file. And when exporting DWFx file in Revit Extractor, the rooms and areas are turned off by design. Finally, I  logged a wish with the ticket number TREX-907. Sorry  for not being helpful at this moment,

Comment: I am not sure if it will be feasibile, while you may probably try to transform 3D room coordinates to 2D sheets, and connect these 2D points on 2D sheet or view